# How can I create a button that both triggers a shortcode and redirects to a specific URL?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and i am using a user role plugin.

I need to create a button that triggers to actions:

1. Fires the shortcode that assigns the user who clicked the button with a specific user role
2. Redirect the user to a specific URL to view their dashboard

How can I add the shortcode [groups_join group="Buyers"]  and the URL www.xyz.com/buyerdashoboard behind a button?

Comment: you would use javacript to do this.  do you have that shortcode available?

Comment: hi yes the shortcode is available: -->   [groups_join group="Buyers"]

Answer (score 1):

First, you want to create an ajax function to trigger your shortcode like:

```
function fire_shortcode(){
    do_shortcode( '[groups_join group="Buyers"]' );
    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_fire_shortcode', 'fire_shortcode' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_fire_shortcode', 'fire_shortcode' );
```

Then in your javascript file add something like:

```
jQuery('.button-selector').click(function(){
    var data = {
        action: 'fire_shortcode',
        arg1: 'value', 
        arg2: 'value'
    };

    var ajaxurl = 'http://yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        console.log('Shortcode fired. Redirecting now...');
        window.location = "http://redirectwebsite.com/";
    });
});
```

Comment: please change the $ sign to jQuery it causes issues in wordpress

Comment: what should I change the $ sign to?

Comment: `wp_ajax_noprivfire_shortcode` should be `wp_ajax_nopriv_fire_shortcode`

Comment: Thanks for all the replied. Anyone else who can confirm if the above code would be the best way for this to work?